# Is there a way to delete files instantly on Windows XP?

Tags: windows

On my Mac and any other Unix machine, when I delete a file by any of the several available methods (`rm` on the command line, drag to trash, press delete key) it usually happens instantly. Occasionally it takes a few seconds if it's a huge file.

On Windows, when I try to delete something a dialog comes up with a progress bar. On my machine the deletion can take 10 to 20 seconds or even more in some cases.

Is there a way to perform a delete operation on Windows XP with no wait period?

Also, is there a way to not have to click those "are you sure..." dialogs?

Comment: The tools used to do programming are programming related. There are many questions not closed on here about tools.

Comment: Now that would wreak havoc. Imagine you accidentally pressing that combination and unrecoverably deleting your files without any confirmation whatsoever. I mean, if you want to automatize this, just use del /q but (me being an idiot) I am personally glad that Windows is idiot-proof.

Comment: It's a matter of preference I think, but I've been using `rm -f` (no confirm step, no recovery possible) for maybe a decade now with no havoc wrecked. It helps that there's source control and backups, but it's never been a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried on the command line?

```
del /q filename
```

Optionally you could also install MinGW or Cygwin to get the same commands available in Windows as in Linux/Unix.

Please note that file deletion might be **slow** if you keep **many files in your Recycle Bin**. Emptying the bin will solve the problem.

You can **permanently bypass the Recycle Bin** by changing the configuration of the Recycle Bin. And you can also configure Windows XP to **skip the confirmation message**. For details check Microsoft's Knowledge Base:

> [HOW TO: Bypass the Recycle Bin When You Delete Files and Folders in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320031)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried shift + DEL?

Comment: shift-del still asks for confirmation, doesn't it

Comment: yeah, it requires confirmation

Comment: Win XP can be configured to skip confirmation. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Many times the deletion time is increased by the use of the trash can. In those cases, deleting directly (Shift - Delete) will speed up the deletion at the cost of unrecoverability (is that proper english?)

Another common reason for slow deletions is the fact that windows will not delete an open file. Just in case a process is exiting and has an open file, the default explorer behavior is waiting a couple of seconds (I believe it is 3 seconds) and retrying the delete operation on the file. This behavior, gets over the annoying fact that sometimes it is the same explorer who has opened the file for a preview.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the freeware Fastcopy to achieve this. Check out:
http://www.themisteriosos.com/delete-large-files-faster.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the trashcan and turn off the "are you sure" nag. You can also choose to delete without a stop at the trashcan first.